# How to write API test case for generic views in DRF?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-urls

Here I'm writing some TestCase for some queryset to view in api and getting error
not a valid function or pattern name. I didn't get any idea what missing here! Is there any solution for this?

views.py

```
class  StudentView(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = StudentDetails.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM 
           collegedetails.college_studentdetails LIMIT 3;')
serializer_class = StudentDetailsSerializers
```

test_views.py

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import status

STUDENT_URL = reverse('student/')
class StudentsDetailsTest(APITestCase):
def test_details(self):
    response = self.client.get(STUDENT_URL, format='json')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

college/urls.py

```
urlpatterns=[

        path('student/',views.StudentView.as_view(), name='student'),
]
```

django.urls.exceptions.NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'student/' not found. 'student/' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

---

Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)

Answer (score 0):

Pass `name` to `reverse` function, not url: `STUDENT_URL = reverse('student')`

Comment: see i pass name to reverse not working  (Reverse for 'student' not found. 'student' is not a valid view function or pattern name).

Comment: Then pass app name too, for ex. `reverse('college:student')`